# how to write a junit testCase for add method?

Tags: java, junit, polynomial-math

here is the add method for polynomial

```
public Polynomilal add (Polynomial poly){

//getA()..etc getters for the coefficients of the polynomial.

    MyDouble aVal=getA().add(poly.getA());
    MyDouble bVal=getB().add(poly.getB());
    MyDouble cVal=getC().add(poly.getC());
    Polynomial addedPoly=new Polynomial(aVal, bVal, cVal);
    return addedPoly;
}
```

and the test case for add method starts with

```
public void testAdd() {
........
........

}
```

Comment: What specifically is your problem? You don't know how to test using JUnit or don't know what behaviour to test or how to test behaviour of add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some of the basics...

The general idea of a unit test is to compare "What you want" with "What you got". A simple assertion is like

```
assertEquals("it better work!", 4 /* expected */, 2 + 2);
```

If you know what aVal should be, you can do

```
assertEquals("aVal should be this", <what you expecte it to be>, aVal);
```

There's a special detail for "double" values, because roundoff causes them to often be not exactly what you expect, so you say:

```
assertEquals("some double value", 1.555555d, 1.0d + 5.0d / 9.0d, .001); // within .001? ok!
```

Anyway, that's the gist of unit tests. Assertions of things you can see. Very handy stuff.

(assertEquals, and friends, are all statically accessible from  TestCase, which most unit tests descend from.)

Answer (score 0):

As addition to david's answer I recommend you to use Custom Assertion pattern described [here](http://xunitpatterns.com/Custom%20Assertion.html). Also I'd consider using parametrized tests for input and expected data as described [here](http://xunitpatterns.com/Parameterized%20Test.html) and using some JUnit specific examples like [the following](http://blogs.oracle.com/jacobc/entry/parameterized_unit_tests_with_junit).

Hope this helps!